# How to compile wine 32 bit on mac using gcc

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compilation, wine

I am trying to compile the 32 bit version of wine on mac. When I do

`./configure --with-wine64=../wine64`

I get the error "Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries.".

I think this is because xcode stopped supporting 32 bit libraries (I have version 10). When I do `which gcc` I get `/usr/bin/gcc`, therefore I think my gcc is came with xcode.

I also installed gcc using `brew install gcc`, but when I do `ls /usr/local/bin/ | grep gcc` I get

```
gcc-8
gcc-ar-8
gcc-nm-8
gcc-ranlib-8
x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0-gcc-8
x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0-gcc-8.2.0
x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0-gcc-ar-8
x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0-gcc-nm-8
x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0-gcc-ranlib-8
```

so I thought I could install a gcc with libraries related with 32 bit support and compile wine like that. But now when I do `./configure CC="gcc-8" --with-wine64=../wine64`, I get

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error:
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

How can I find a workaround to compile 32 bit wine (version 3.21)

Comment: wine64 is a 64 bit version of wine, only available for Linux Distros, have you tried installing wine via HomeBrew with `brew install wine`?

Comment: yes that works but it installs version 3.0.4, which has bugs with the programs I am trying to run (and they are said to be fixed in later versions)

Comment: and wine64 works actually. only when I try to compile wine32 I get problems (although brew is able to install a previous version of it)

Comment: Quoting straight from the [docs](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS/Building) here, but maybe try and change your configure flags: `./configure CC="clang" CXX="clang++" CFLAGS="-std=gnu89 -g"`?

Comment: nope, same error

Comment: I actually found a workaround to bypass the problem now (dont know if it will cause problems later though) `../configure --host="x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0" CC="gcc-8" --with-wine64=../wine64 --with-wine-tools="../../wine64/"`

Comment: now this gives the problem `error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check`

Comment: That's cross compiling, and that error is mostly stemming from your configure file, it has to be configured for cross-compilation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185852/discussion-between-ozgen-eren-and-gke).